# PHP extensions are not recognized by Apache

Tags: php, windows, apache, php-extension

Running `php -m` on the command line I can see all of installed PHP extensions. However, on `phpinfo()` output I can not find some of them e.g. mbstring. What is wrong with it? I use PHP 5.6 and Apache http server 2.4 on windows 7 all 64b.

Comment: Command line and sever php may use different ini files

Comment: I have checked it.They Both use the same php.ini file

Answer (score 1):

> *Did you really not overlook anything?*

- [Add PHP settings](https://github.com/SuriyaaKudoIsc/localhost/blob/Windows-8.1/Server/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf#L536) in `httpd.conf`:

`LoadModule php5_module "your_path_to\php\php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "your_path_to\php"`

- [Remove the comma](https://github.com/SuriyaaKudoIsc/localhost/blob/Windows-8.1/Server/langs/php/5.6.11/php.ini#L888) in php.ini: `;extension=php_mbstring.dll` to `extension=php_mbstring.dll`!

> It should work now.

Comment: @Iman Ghafoori: If this post is helpful for you. Please mark this answer as accepted and vote this up. Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. Thanks. :-)